# Добавить текст в слайдер (баннер)

Tags: opencart

Добрый день, у меня на главной идут 4 слайдера(баннера), хочу сделать на каждом разные надписи ''акции,новинки и бла-бла-бла'' Как это можно сделать? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: какой это модуль?

Comment: Это баннер в списке модулей

Comment: напишите название модуля или покажите принтскрин его позиции в админке.

Comment: https://monosnap.com/file/NVBSWJcDrO5ye4vNHqQ8s4SfzA5dUe#

Comment: Все справился,спс

Comment: Если вы нашли решение, не поленитесь дать ответ в своей теме. И вам +, и кому-нибудь, когда-нибудь помощь.